# pause/start AVAudioPlayer without glitchy pops

Tags: iphone, audio, ios, avaudioplayer

I'm playing back a longish audio file (20 seconds or so) using AVAudioPlayer. I need to be able to pause and start in the middle of the file. When I pause or start while the audio is playing, there's a noticeable "pop" as the audio starts or finishes.

I've been able to improve the situation by doing a very fast fade-out (setting the volume multiple times using *performSelector: withObject: afterDelay*. But the sound is still a little glitchy with this technique.

Is there a standard way to start/pause AVAudioPlayer without these glitches?

Answer (score 2):

Try sending the -prepareToPlay to your AVAudioPlayer object when it's paused. This will pre-load the sound.

If this doesn't work, try accelerating your fade-out by reducing the delay in the performSelector: withObject: afterDelay. Go crazy, milliseconds.

If this doesn't work too, try using a cleaner, higher-quality audio file (without irrelevant background noises)

If none of this works, please explain how the audio file in your app is being used in further detail.

Comment: performSelector: withObject: afterDelay seems to be limited in resolution by the run loop. There's a limit to how small the delay can be. Don't remember what it is exactly, but I'm not sure you can use that method with delays in the millisecond range.

Comment: sure you can, if it limits it'll use the minimum allowed anyway, so it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the lower level APIs (Audio Queues or RemoteIO).  Smoothly ramp a multiplication factor from 1.0 to 0.0 over some number of PCM samples. Use that factor for the sample-by-sample gain factor in your own DSP audio mixer.  Ramp from 0.0 to 1.0 on restart.  Linear or an ease-in/ease-out half-cosine curve.

Comment: Trouble is I'm playing back compressed files, so don't have easy access to the PCM data.

Comment: Here's some sample code which may help getting pcm data from a compressed file: http://www.cogs.susx.ac.uk/users/nc81/code.html